# control-panel not list iPlanetAMPolicyService - openam 13

Tags: openam, opendj, opends

I'm working on customize profile attributes as per this [link](https://backstage.forgerock.com/docs/openam/13/dev-guide/chap-customizing#sec-custom-attr). I did the ditto same as per that link but I'm not successful.

**Short description of what I have done**

1. Add below content in /root/openam/config/xml/amUser.xml under user node

   ```
   <AttributeSchema name="customAttribute"
       type="single"
       syntax="string"
       any="display"
       i18nKey="Custom Attribute">
   </AttributeSchema>
   ```
2. Delete **iPlanetAMUserService**

   ```
   $ /opt/openam-tool/openam/bin/ssoadm delete-svc --adminid amadmin --password-file /tmp/pwd.txt --servicename iPlanetAMUserService
   ```
3. Create iPlanetAMUserService

   ```
   /opt/openam-tool/openam/bin/ssoadm create-svc --adminid amadmin --password-file /tmp/pwd.txt --xmlfile /root/openam/config/xml/amUser.xml
   ```
4. Add scchema definitions as per the link

   ```
   $ /root/openam/opends/bin/ldapmodify --port 389 --hostname frock.gworks.mobi --bindDN "cn=Directory Manager" --bindPassword gworks.mobi1 --filename /tmp/custom-attr.ldif
   ```
5. Top realm -> data store -> embeddj-> Add customObjectclass & customAttribute
6. To Allow Users To Update the New Attribute

   ```
   $ sh /root/openam/opends/bin/control-panel
   ```

In **step 6** I can't find **iPlanetAMPolicyService** for edit **sun-key** value

Easy for your reference  https://postimg.org/image/it7ovadwh/

can you please help me to proceed further?

Comment: You should have used update-svc instead of delete+create by the way. Also you just need to drill down the last ou=services entry to find the rest of the entries.

Comment: @PeterMajor I believe I ask to right person. I can't able to raise new questions in openam forum is there any issues or restriction? when I submit new question, after load my question is not in list.